# How is it possible to insert and select inserted data in one SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have some function `insert_info(num IN NUMBER)` which clears some `temp` table's content and rewrites in with data and adds amount of columns equal to `num` from arguments list. I need to call this function and retrieve values from `temp` table in one SQL query, something like:

```
select insert_info(5), t.* from dual, temp t
```

However, I get the old values from the table and after that the table content is updated. I'm using Oracle 10g.

Comment: You might need a stored procedure for this.

Comment: but is it possible to call it from simple SQL?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm Oracle Database always enforces statement-level read consistency. This guarantees that all the data returned by a single query comes from a single point in time—the time that the query began. Therefore, a query never sees dirty data or any of the changes made by transactions that commit during query execution. As query execution proceeds, only data committed before the query began is visible to the query. The query does not see changes committed after statement execution begins.

Comment: Please show function code. "select" clause working _after_ "from" get data.

Comment: @Mike the function works exactly how I explained, the code is too long so I just tried to explain shortly what it does.

Comment: @BekaBot Why you do call function in "select" clause ? you need it to change the data at the time of reading each row? Function with automus_transaction pragma ?

Comment: May by you need to read from function ? Use "table functions" like this (`select * from table(insert_info(5))` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
create or replace function show_table_data(p_info in number) return temp%rowtype is
  cursor c_temp is
    select
      *
    from
      temp;

  p_table c_temp%rowtype;
  p_status varchar2(4000) := insert_info(p_info); -- not sure what your function returns;
begin
  open c_temp;
  fetch c_temp
    into p_table;
  close p_table;

  return p_table;
end;

select show_table_data(5) from dual;
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't test that, was pretty sure it will work. Fixed the code now. However using this code i get internal pls... internal error, which is the cause of our recent migration of db, so i can't be sure if this works. Tell me if that works.

Comment: It will not work. Your p_status varchar2(4000) := insert_info(p_info); is not correct. The function return type should match with your variable declared. You must test your code before posting as answer.

Comment: "insert_info(p_info)" is the function you provided in your example. As i commented after variable assigment, i'm not sure what your function returns, so i used it entirely as an example on how you could execute your function. You should change that variable depending on what "insert_info()" function returns.

Comment: Lastly i did not ask this question. Check out who has asked this question. i am just showing errors in your code.